# Android. Set backgound color without change the shape

Tags: android, xml, button, background, shapes

I'd like to set the background color of my button without change the shape.

The button is the following:

```
 <Button 
   android:id="@+id/button_color"
   style="@style/button_menu"
   android:background="@drawable/gray_button"
   android:text="" />
```

where the gray_button.xml contains information of the shape, a rounded shape in my case.

If I use the function

```
colorButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(r, g, b));
```

will also change the shape.

How can I do?

Comment: use setColorFilter on your Button's background Drawable

Comment: Thank you. setColorFilter works

Answer (score 0):

You can add background color in gray_button.xml.